# Twitter API: metrics for a list of users on a monthly basis?

Tags: r, twitter, metrics

I am working in R and trying to extract Twitter metrics i.e. number of tweets, retweets, likes, followers for a list of twitter users. Ideally on a monthly basis (e.g. Jan 2012 user xy 12 tweets, 10 retweets, 20 likes, +5 followers). Unfortunately, I am completely clueless and all the endpoints that I have found on twitter developer do not seem to five me information on a time scale. Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Thank you so much in advance for your support!!

Comment: can you share code and data you have tried?

Comment: Check out the `rtweet` package: https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/

Comment: To start with I have tried timeline, search_tweets and search.twitter, all not resulting in what I need unfortunately